# I want to take the input from a JavaScript and send it to a python script and back

Tags: javascript, python

I want to take the input from a JavaScript and send it to a python script and back which the output of the python script gets sent back to the same JavaScript file to get processed. Seen by the code below i have tried using flask but am not sure if it is 100% working. This code is made to take the input (a.co link) on my website then send that to the python script to make it a amazon.ca link which then gets sent back to the JavaScript file to turn it into a affiliated link which then gets displayed on my website as an iframe.

The python code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS # Import the CORS class
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

def convert_to_amazon_ca(a_co_link):
   try:
       # Get the ASIN from the a.co link
       response = requests.get(a_co_link)
       if response.status_code != 200:
           print(f"Failed to fetch the page. Status code: {response.status_code}")
           return None
       
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
       canonical_link = soup.find('link', {'rel': 'canonical'})
       
       if not canonical_link:
           print("Unable to find canonical link.")
           return None
       
       product_id = canonical_link.get('href')
       
       parsed_url = urlparse(product_id)
       path_components = parsed_url.path.split('/')
       asin_index = path_components.index('dp') + 1 if 'dp' in path_components else -1
       
       if asin_index != -1 and len(path_components) > asin_index:
           asin = path_components[asin_index]
       else:
           print("ASIN not found in the URL.")
           return None

       # Search for the ASIN on Amazon.ca
       amazon_ca_link = f"https://www.amazon.ca/dp/{asin}"
       return amazon_ca_link
   
   except Exception as e:
       print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
       return None

@app.route('/convert', methods=['POST'])
def handle_conversion():
   data = request.get_json()
   amazon_link = data.get('link')

   amazon_ca_link = convert_to_amazon_ca(amazon_link)

   return jsonify({'amazon_ca_link': amazon_ca_link})

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

The JS:

```
console.log('JavaScript code is loaded and executed');

function convertToAmazonCA(link) {
  // Replace "a.co" with "amazon.ca"
  const convertedLink = link.replace('a.co', 'amazon.ca');
  return convertedLink;
}

window.convertToAffiliate = function() {
  const inputField = document.getElementById('amazonLinkInput');
  const link = inputField.value.trim();
  const affiliateTag = ''; // Replace with your affiliate tag

   // Replace "a.co" with "amazon.ca" in the link
   const convertedLink = convertToAmazonCA(link);

   const asin = extractASIN(convertedLink);
   const linkId = extractLinkID(convertedLink);
 
   if (asin) {
     const convertedAffiliateLink = `//rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?lt1=_blank&bc1=000000&IS2=1&bg1=FFFFFF&fc1=000000&lc1=0000FF&t=${affiliateTag}&language=en_CA&o=15&p=8&l=as4&m=amazon&f=ifr&ref=as_ss_li_til&asins=${asin}&linkId=${linkId}`;
 
     const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
     iframe.src = convertedAffiliateLink;
     iframe.setAttribute('width', '120');
     iframe.setAttribute('height', '240');
     iframe.setAttribute('align-items', 'center');
     iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no'); // Add scrolling="no" attribute
     iframe.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // Add overflow: hidden; CSS property
     iframe.style.border = 'none';
 
     const amazonLinksDiv = document.getElementById('amazonLinks');
     amazonLinksDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous content
     amazonLinksDiv.appendChild(iframe);
   } else {
     document.getElementById('convertedLink').innerHTML = 'Not a valid Amazon link or ASIN not found.';
   }
 }
 
 function extractASIN(link) {
   const asinMatch = link.match(/\/(?:dp|gp\/product|exec\/obidos|aw\/d)\/(B[0-9A-Z]{9}|\w{10})|a\.co\/(?:[^\/]+\/)?(dp|gp\/product|exec\/obidos|aw\/d)\/(\w{10})/);
   console.log('Link:', link);
   console.log('Match:', asinMatch);
   if (asinMatch) {
     return asinMatch[1] || asinMatch[3];
   } else {
     return '';
   }
 }
 
 function extractLinkID(link) {
   const linkIdMatch = link.match(/coliid=([\w\d]{10})/);
   return linkIdMatch ? linkIdMatch[1] : null;
 }
 
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   const convertButton = document.getElementById('convertButton');
 
   convertButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
     convertToAffiliate();
   });
 });
```

I have tried using flash but i am consistently getting an error 405

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/convert net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)
(anonymous) @ script.js:31
script.js:39 Response status code: 405
script.js:49 Error: Failed to convert link
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:46:15)
```

Comment: How exactly are you posting the data in your javascript code because when i use postman and POST the data using the body,  i receive the data on the flask application just fine.